# Swap binary bits in python

Tags: python, binary, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to swap the last two bits in a binary number with the previous 2 bits.

E.g. I want 0b11101011 to become 0b11101110.

How can this be achieved in python using bitwise operators?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-bits-in-a-given-number/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be

```
bin(a & ~15 | (a & 3) << 2 | (a & 12) >> 2)

# a & ~15          -- a with the last 4 bits cleared
# | (a & 3) << 2   -- or with the lowest 2 bits (0 & 1) shifted 2 steps to the left
# | (a & 12) >> 2  -- or with bits 2 and 3 shifted 2 steps to the right.

a = 0b11101011
bin(a & ~15 | (a & 3) << 2 | (a & 12) >> 2)
# '0b11101110'
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see with [calcperm](http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php)*, it can be done with a bit_permute_step (aka [delta swap](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/General+Setwise+Operations#Shifting%20Bitboards-Swapping%20Bits)), like this

```
def bit_permute_step(x, m, shift):
    t = ((x >> shift) ^ x) & m
    x = (x ^ t) ^ (t << shift)
    return x

x = bit_permute_step(x, 3, 2)
```

..or something like that. Please correct my Python if I made any mistakes.

*: fill in `2 3 0 1 4 5 6` (or more bits but the answer will be the same)